# Using callback to get image pixel data

Tags: javascript, callback

I am relatively new to JavaScript. The concept of callbacks is confusing me a bit coming from an OOP background

I am trying to create a hidden canvas for an image object and then get its pixel data.

I have an ImageObject on which I would eventually want to store all the properties like image, pixels and so on.. Inside start() , first I get references to maincanvas and mainctx. Then I load the image and once the image is drawn, I store its pixel data in ImageObject.pixels

However inside the start(), the code runs asynchronously and the log statement to display ImageObject.pixels return null

How do I use callbacks to solve this?

Below is my code

```
ImageObject = {};
var MainCtx;
var MainCanvas;
//get the image pixel properties

function start()
{
    MainCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    MainCtx = MainCanvas.getContext('2d');
    ImageObject.image = loadImage();
    console.log(" Image pixels " +ImageObject.pixels); // -> displays NULL because code runs asynchronously, how do I use callback here to avoid this? 
}

function loadImage()
{
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = 'image.jpg';
    image.addEventListener('load',function()
        {
            MainCtx.drawImage(image,MainCanvas.width/2,MainCanvas.height/2);
            console.log("width here" +image.width+ " maincanvas " +MainCanvas+ " mainctx " +MainCtx+ " image " +image);
            ImageObject.pixels = getImagePixels(image); //-> store pixel data in the image 
        });
    return image; 
}


function getImagePixels(img)
{
    var c = getCanvas(img.width,img.height);
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    return ctx.getImageData(0,0,c.width,c.height);
}

function getCanvas(w,h)
{
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    c.width = w;
    c.height = h;
    return c;
}

start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple add new function that will be called when all process is finished.
change

```
function start()
{
    MainCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    MainCtx = MainCanvas.getContext('2d');
    ImageObject.image = loadImage();
    console.log(" Image pixels " +ImageObject.pixels); // -> displays NULL because code runs asynchronously, how do I use callback here to avoid this? 
}
```

to

```
function start()
{
    MainCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    MainCtx = MainCanvas.getContext('2d');
    ImageObject.image = loadImage();
}
```

and change

```
function loadImage()
{
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = 'image.jpg';
    image.addEventListener('load',function()
        {
            MainCtx.drawImage(image,MainCanvas.width/2,MainCanvas.height/2);
            console.log("width here" +image.width+ " maincanvas " +MainCanvas+ " mainctx " +MainCtx+ " image " +image);
            ImageObject.pixels = getImagePixels(image); //-> store pixel data in the image 
        });
    return image; 
}
```

to

```
function loadImage()
{
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = 'image.jpg';
    image.addEventListener('load',function()
        {
            MainCtx.drawImage(image,MainCanvas.width/2,MainCanvas.height/2);
            console.log("width here" +image.width+ " maincanvas " +MainCanvas+ " mainctx " +MainCtx+ " image " +image);
            ImageObject.pixels = getImagePixels(image); //-> store pixel data in the image 
            done();
        });
    return image; 
}
```

and add this

```
function done()
{
    console.log(" Image pixels " +ImageObject.pixels); // -> displays NULL because code runs asynchronously, how do I use callback here to avoid this? 
}
```